# Solve inside of InputField is not dynamic

Tags: equation-solving, dynamic, inputfield

On the 7th line, I have an InputField that I want to dynamically change as I change the input. It solves an equation that is later used to determine the change in y intercept in the graph. However, the value (h) doesn't change as I change the other values. What am I doing wrong here?

I included a picture here. When I change the values in yellow, they should change the value in blue.
[image]

```
Manipulate[
   DynamicModule[{p = 0, c = 1, d = 1, f = 0, \[Theta] = 0, i = 1, j = 1, k = 2}, Deploy[Style[
     Panel[Grid[Transpose[{{"P", "C", "D", "F", "\[Theta]", "h", "height", "left", "right"},
         {InputField[Dynamic[p]], InputField[Dynamic[c]], 
          InputField[Dynamic[d]], InputField[Dynamic[f]], 
          InputField[Dynamic[\[Theta]]], 
          InputField[Dynamic[h = x /.Solve[2 == x*Cos[\[Theta]] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[\[Theta]], x, Reals][[1]]],
          InputField[Dynamic[i]], 
          InputField[Dynamic[j]], InputField[Dynamic[k]]]}}],
       Alignment -> Right], ImageMargins -> 10, DefaultOptions ->
       {InputField -> {ContinuousAction -> True, FieldSize -> {{5, 30}, {1, Infinity}}}}]]] Dynamic[Show[
     {Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red,
        Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}]},
       PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> True,
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
      ParametricPlot[{x*Cos[\[Theta]] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[\[Theta]], 
    x*Sin[\[Theta]] + (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Cos[\[Theta]] + h*Sin[\[Theta]] + (p*h^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + h) Cos[\[Theta]] + i}, {x, 0, h}, Axes -> True]}]]]]
```

Thanks!

edit: small error in pasting

edit2: some changes, pasted below

```
    Manipulate[h = x /. Quiet@Solve[2 == x*Cos[\[Theta]] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[\[Theta]], x, Reals][[1]];
 Text[h]
  Show[{Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}]},
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-3, 3}},
     Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
    ParametricPlot[{x*Cos[\[Theta]] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[\[Theta]],x*Sin[\[Theta]] + (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Cos[\[Theta]] + h*Sin[\[Theta]] + (p*h^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + h) Cos[\[Theta]] + i}, 
 {x, 0, h}, Axes -> True]}],
 {p, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, {c, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, 
 {d, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, {f, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, 
 {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi], ControlType -> InputField}, {i, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, 
 {j, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, {k, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, 
 {l, 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}]
```

Comment: Why aren't you calling the variables to be changed in the second argument of `Manipulate[]`?

Comment: Would that be the correct way to do it? I'm new at this, so I'm just learning as I'm going.

Comment: I just looked up Manipulate. I'm a bit confused about what you mean. Can you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for all this dynamic stuff, you can use `Solve[]` in conjunction with `Manipulate[]`, and let `Manipulate[]` handle the dynamic stuff.

```
Manipulate[
 h = x /. Quiet@
    Solve[2 == 
       x*Cos[θ] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[θ], x, 
      Reals][[1]]; 
 Show[{Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2, 1}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
   ParametricPlot[{x*
       Cos[θ] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[θ], 
     x*Sin[θ] + (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Cos[θ] + 
      h*Sin[θ] + (p*h^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + h) Cos[θ] + 
      i}, {x, 0, h}, Axes -> True]}], {ρ, 0, 1, 0.1}, {c, 0.2, 2,
   0.2}, {d, 0.2, 2, 0.2}, {f, 0, 2, 0.2}, {p, 0, 2, 0.2}, {θ, 
  0, π, 0.1 π}, {i, -2, 2, 0.5},ControlType -> InputField]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't working the way it should be. The end of the curve isn't intersecting with the corner of the box. Also, what is the \[Rho] for? And is there anyway to get InputFields back? Thanks again!

Comment: @rxc370 I cannot account for the validity of your expressions, this code changes the value of `h` dynamically as you asked. As for the inputfield, just add `ControlType -> InputField` to the `Manipulate[]`. I mistook `p` for `rho`.

Comment: Sorry, last question. If I wanted to output the value of a variable as text somewhere, how would I do it? Before, I just made it a dynamic InputField.

Comment: @rxc370 `Text[]` is a graphics directive

Answer (score 0):

Got everything working the way I want it to. Here is the code below if anyone ever wants to model a cantilever bending on a box.

```
Manipulate[h = x /. Quiet@Solve[k == x*Cos[\[Theta]] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[\[Theta]], x, Reals][[1]];
 a = x /.Quiet@Solve[l == x*Cos[\[Theta]] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[\[Theta]], x, Reals][[1]];
 b = a*Sin[\[Theta]] + (p*a^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + a) Cos[\[Theta]] - h*Sin[\[Theta]] - (p*h^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + h) Cos[\[Theta]];
 Text[ h, b]
  Show[{Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Rectangle[{j, 0}, {k, i}]},
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-3, 3}},
     Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
    ParametricPlot[{x*Cos[\[Theta]] - (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Sin[\[Theta]],
      x*Sin[\[Theta]] + (p*x^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + x) Cos[\[Theta]] - h*Sin[\[Theta]] - (p*h^2)/(6*c*d) (3 f + h) Cos[\[Theta]] + i}, {x, 0, h}, Axes -> True]}],
 {p, 0, 1, ControlType -> InputField}, {{c, 1}, 0, 10, ControlType -> InputField},
 {{d, 1}, 0, 10, ControlType -> InputField}, {f, 0, 10, ControlType -> InputField},
 {{\[Theta], 0}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], ControlType -> InputField}, {{i, 1}, 0, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, 
 {{j, 1}, 0, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, {{k, 2}, 0, 2, ControlType -> InputField}, 
 {{l, 0}, , 0.2, 2, ControlType -> InputField}]
```